# Are the imported packages of fragments included in the host bundle classpath?

Tags: java, osgi

I have some problems regarding OSGi fragments and `Class.forName()`. The example below illustrates my problem.

I have a third-party bundle `Foo`. I cannot modify `Foo` in any way. The bundle contains the following class:

```
public class Serializer {
    public String summarizeClass(String className) {
        Class<?> myClass = Class.forName(className);
        ...
    }
}
```

If I call this method from bundle `Bar` for `org.myPackage.MyClass`, it will fail, since `MyClass` is not on the classpath of bundle `Foo`.

Can I simply add a fragment `Foo.fragment` with a dependency to `Bar` to modify the classpath of bundle `Foo`? Or does this dependency only apply for classes within the fragment?

Long story short:
What are the semantics of `Class.forName()` in OSGi, when executed in a class of the Host bundle? Does it include:

- Q: The bundle classes? A: Yes.
- Q: The classes contained in the fragment? A: Yes. [Source](http://olegz.wordpress.com/2008/11/05/osgi-and-classforname/)
- Q: The imported packages and the packages exported from required bundles? A: Yes.
- **Q: The imported packages and the packages exported from required bundles of all fragments? A: I don't know.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

See section 3.14 of the OSGi Core spec, release 5.0.0.

Summary: You can add a fragment with just an Import-Package header or a Require-Bundle header. The clauses in these headers are appended tot he corresponding headers in the host bundle. So if you add:

```
 Fragment-Host:  Foo;version="[1,2)"
 Import-Package: org.myPackage;version="[1,2)"
```

Then the Foo bundle will be able to see your MyClass.

Please note that the code in `summarizeClass` makes an assumption that there is a single class space and that a class *name* uniquely identifies a specific class. However, large applications have dependency trees that frequently use conflicting versions of the same dependencies. For these cases, this assumption is therefore very wrong. OSGi guarantees that any class sees a consistent class space when resolved although different bundles can see different class spaces. This feature requires that OSGi knows what packages your bundle requires. Sadly, Class.forName has other bad qualities as well (it pins classes in memory) and is almost always quite unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you for the comments. The actual problem I am struggling with is the Acceleo templating language which can use java classes to invoke extra methods. It is OSGi-aware but has some issues in finding the right bundle for specific contexts (here: testing with Tycho). The correction here is clearly in the Acceleo-code, but this specific question is for an immediate workaround.